# How to make a batch script to run commands on a remote machine using credentials

Tags: c#, docker, batch-file, remote-server

I have wrote some batch scripts to perform docker commands on a machine and made it run using c# program. I can successfully run those batch scripts in my local machine, but I want it to run on a remote machine. How can I do that by giving remote machine access credentials? I am looking for batch commands that will first connect to the remote machine and then execute its body in remote machine. 
A sample batch script is as below.

```
::Start an exited container
::Iam expecting some code here to connect to a remote machine
@echo off
docker start %1
```

Or, Is there any option to do it through c# program?

Comment: Any option to be able to ssh to that machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using PsExec 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec

This is a light weight replacement for telnet

Answer (score 3):

I failed to find a method to run batch scripts on a remote machine,  but I used powershell scripting instead of batch scripts. If you can use powershell scripts instead of batch scripts, you can use this method.

```
set-item wsman:localhost\client\trustedhosts -value <Remote_computer_name> -Force
$pword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String <Remote_machine_password> -AsPlainText -Force
$user = <Remote_userName>
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $pword
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <Remote_computer_name> -filepath <ps1_file_path> -Credential $Credential
```

Running the above commands in a powershell administrator window will run the scripts in `<ps1_file_path>` in a remote machine.

---

You have to take into consider that, the command 
`set-item wsman:localhost\client\trustedhosts -value <Remote_computer_name> -Force` 
will add the remote machine into trusted hosts list.
Also, the command `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass` will allow all powershell scripts to run on our machine and I'm not sure it is safe to use. 
Hope it help somebody in some way, but you must do research to make sure this method is safe. 
Refer:

> [Execution Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-6)

Answer (score 2):

Please try connecting using WinRM. Some sample info-

[remote command execution](https://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/)

and

[winrm-command referance](https://ss64.com/nt/winrm-remote.html)

Or ssh server on Windows server - example 
[WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server)

Hope it helps.